# Doing Join query using CDBCriteria

Tags: php, inner-join, criteria, yii

I am trying to do a Join query using CDBCriteria in Yii framework. The issue is the join query works successfully but it does not display the columns from other tables.

I am doing in the following way

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->order = 't.id desc';

$criteria->select = '*';

$criteria->join = ' INNER JOIN table2 INNER JOIN table3 INNER JOIN table4';
```

When i run this, I can see only the mail table1 columns displayed. Other columns are not shown.

In my model class, I have the relation has

```
public function relations()
{
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
      'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'DmPhoneUser', 'user_id'),
      'command' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'DmOtaCommand', 'command_id'),
      'partner' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'DmPartner', 'partner_id'),
    );
}
```

## ********************************************************************************************

```
public function actionGetHistory($start, $per_page)
{
    $partner_id = '10';
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 't.history_id desc';
    $criteria->select = 't.*, table2.*';
    $criteria->join = ' INNER JOIN table2 ON t.command_id = table2.command_id';
    $result = Table_1_class::model()->with('command')->findAll();
    $history_data = CJSON::encode($result);
    echo $history_data;
}
```

here command_id is common in table1 and table2.

This is how I am using the criteria code.

Comment: Can you show the code where you're using this criteria? Active Record does not pull arbitrary column values into created objects, only the ones it knows about. You should be using `$criteria->with('relation1', 'relation2', ...)` to tell it to fetch related records in other tables.

Comment: try to change `*` to `t.*, table2.*, table3.*`

Comment: I have added the code to the above question. U can find it after the stars. The function name is actionGetHistory($start, $per_page) { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said, Yii's Active Record implementation will only use columns which are defined in the table itself or the tables you are linking to through `with`, not arbitrary columns you return in the resultset.

Solution 1: Define a relation to `table2`, add that relation to `with`, and get rid of `join`. Then you'll probably need to convert each returned object to an array - `CJSON::encode` will not handle a model with relations well.

Solution 2: Use `Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SQL query")->queryAll();` instead of Active Record. This will produce an array of arrays, which `CJSON::encode` will have no problem with.

Comment: You are right DECODER. CJSON::encode doesnt go well with the model relations. Solution 2 worked good and was the best. :) I really appreciate your help and thank you so much.....

Comment: Oh sorry. I am new here. I didnt know about this. Anyways done the needful :) Thanks again.