# Yii join using CDbCriteria not showing columns from second table

Tags: php, yii

I am using the `CDbCriteria` to join two tables restaurants and tables. A restaurant can have multiple tables. I want to get the list of restaurants along with the number of tables in that particular restaurant.

I am using the following code :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select = "t.*, COUNT(t2.id) as rowCount";
$criteria->group = "t2.restaurantId";
$criteria->join = "LEFT JOIN {{tables}} t2 ON t.id = t2.restaurantId";
$criteria->condition = "t.clientId = ".Yii::app()->user->clientId;
$restaurants = Restaurants::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

When I try to display the value of `rowCount` it is showing `Property "Restaurants.tableCount" is not defined`. Also please tell me if this is the correct method of doing things in Yii as I am new to Yii

Comment: Please use the search first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+property+not+defined - before you use a property you should ensure it exists otherwise you'll see an error if it isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii's Active Record [doesn't work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316652/doing-join-query-using-cdbcriteria-in-yii-framework), it can only retrieve columns that are defined in the table schemas, not arbitrary ones.

There is one exception to that statement which you might find useful - a [STAT relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query) can be defined on the Restaurant model to count tables in that restaurant, and then you will be able to read it via Active Record. The linked page has a few good examples of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the attribute **rowCount** in the **Restaurants** model as a virtual attribute, then you'll be able to retrieve it through the CDBCriteria you have defined.